# Is .setId() the most efficient way to create a bunch of objects in Android programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to create a bunch of switches in Android.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        Switch switchTag = new Switch(this);
        switchTag.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        switchTag.setText("");
        switchTag.setId(j + 1 + i);
        row.addView(switchTag);
                });
            }

            layout.addView(row);
```

But I have not been able to find a way to call the switches so I can do things with them. Usually, if I have defined a switch, I can make statements like

```
myswitch.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But that doesn't work if the switch's name is an integer

```
1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

## My Question

Is `.setId()` the most efficient way to create a bunch of objects in Android programmatically?

If it is, how do I call the switches so that I can do things to them? Calling them by integer doesn't work.

Comment: I'm confused... Why would  its name be an integer? You can set the listener on `switchTag`. You could also add them to a Arraylist to store them later

Comment: Doesn't `switchTag.setId(j + 1 + i);` set the Id of the object equal to an integer?

Comment: Yes, the ID isn't the variable name, though. You don't even need an ID unless you later plan to use findViewById

Comment: I want to generate a set of switches and then store the value of them in an array once the user has entered their response. It's a form of Yes/No questions. Is my current approach sensible or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if findViewById is necessary for my purposes, though I have been using that a bit. That's why I thought I needed the Id

Comment: You can add the switch objects directly to an Arraylist. You can also attach the click listener to them as you insert them into the layout

Comment: `But that doesn't work if the switch's name is an integer` variable names can not start with a digit. This is one of the rules that Java enforces on variable and method names. Besides, *view ID* and *variable names* are completely different and independent things!